# On creating a popOver in ionic, <TypeError: ev.target.getBoundingClientRect is not a function> shows

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, popover

I am trying to create a popover on the click of mouse event.
On event calling, the popover Create() method gets called, but the following error shows up every time I perform the mouse click event.
"TypeError: ev.target.getBoundingClientRect is not a function"

The code is:

** Function.service.ts **

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt: Event) {
      this.presentPopover(evt);
    });

async presentPopover(myEvent: Event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
      component: PopOverPagePage,   //Generated as a page
      componentProps:   {
        coordinates: this.coord  // Coordinates captured on in someFunction() already
      },
      event: myEvent
    });
    popover.present();
  }
```

Comment: Did you tried something like event.target, to target the element itself?

Comment: No. Actually I am a beginner into Ionic. Can you please explain in detail as to how I should proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this fix for current issue : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14324

Comment: This didn't help much. Any other help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the `event` helps as stated in the [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/14324#issuecomment-381311474) Vladimir has linked to in the comments, but in an even simpler regard:

```
let event: any = {
    target : {
        getBoundingClientRect : () => {
            return {
            
            };
        }
    }
};
```